# Why has job history stopped updating on BigQuery UI since February 19, 2015?

Tags: user-interface, google-bigquery

I noticed that since the incident that occurred on Feb 18-19 2015, when upload jobs started backing up, I no longer see recent jobs in the BigQuery UI after Feb 19. I know that I have jobs running; my application submits jobs every 3 minutes or so, and I can check the staus of these jobs using the python API. But when I jo to the UI, I no longer can see any activity there.

Comment: Hey! I think this may have a better place in here https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list :).

Comment: Job listing works for me in both the Bigquery web UI and the bq.py command line client. I am able to run various job types and see them show up in the recent job listing. If you are having problems, please include a project id and timestamp of recent incorrect results and we can investigate further. Thank you.

Comment: Nope, I don't use ap engine at all; I use compute engine for back-end processing.

Answer (score 3):

The web UI shows the jobs that the logged in user has run.

If your web application is submitting and running jobs, then they are running under your web application's identity. In this case, the Bigquery web UI won't show you those jobs.

You can see all jobs run in a project from the bq.py client using `bq ls -a -j`. The `-j` will list jobs, and the `-a` will list them for all users.

Comment: This is a distinct change in behavior of the UI from my perspective with no change on my side to cause it. The web application identity is my application identity. Or at least it was until Feb 19. The change in behavior correlates to this incident:

SUMMARY:
Between Tuesday 17 February and Wednesday 18 February 2015, load and export jobs to the BigQuery service experienced significant increases in latency for a period of 29 hours.  If your application was affected by this increase in latency, we apologize.